# Конкатенация строк без библиотеки string.h

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_SIZE1 1024
#define STR_SIZE2 1024

char  StrCat(char  *f,char *s)
{
    char *ptr1,*ptr2;
    char array1,array2;
    ptr1 = &f;
    array1 = *f;
    ptr2 = &s;
    array2 = *s;
    return array1,array2;
}

int main()
{
    char first[STR_SIZE1];
    char second[STR_SIZE2];
    printf("Please enter first string: ");
    scanf("%s", first);
    printf("Please enter second string: ");
    scanf("%s", second);
    printf("%s%s",StrCat(second,first));

    return 0;
}
```

Код компилируется, но после ввода строк программа вылетает. Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка и что следует исправить?

Comment: эм... а кто вас так учил использовать оператор запятая? P.S. можете убрать вызов функции и сделать `printf("%s%s",second,first);` и всё

Comment: Очень бы хотелось услышать, что, по-вашему, делает ваш код `Strcat()`...

Comment: Печально, что ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос вас ничему не научил. Вы упорно продолжаете пытаться сделать что то со строками, просто поиграв указателями на них. **C** сильно отличается от большинства других языков именно тем, что тут можно напрямую обращаться к памяти. Это огромный плюс. Но и конечно большой минус, для не осознавших как работает процессор и память. Строка  - это набор байт в памяти и в C что бы что либо сделать со строкой вы должны в цикле обойти каждый из этих байт и сделать с ним что то.

Answer (score 2):

Блин...

```
char * s1 = first;
char * s2 = second;
for(;*s1;++s1);
while(*s1++ = *s2++);
```

Примерно так. Лишь бы в `first` места хватило для `second`...